# Incremental variable names inside PHP loop

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having to read a series of X and Y values out of a table for plotting with pChart....i know this works for single series but I've been trying to get the following code to work for several series for a while now. $pidresults are the output of a search form which are used to extract the various X and Y pairs from another table which uses that value as its foreign key.

```
 $pidresults = $_SESSION['pidresults'];
    $pidsize = count($pidresults);
    // select plottable data from sampleSlave table
    for ($i=0; $i<$pidsize; $i++) {
    $val = $pidresults[$i];
    $sql="SELECT * FROM sampleSlave WHERE masterID=$val AND xaxisdata>=1 ORDER BY xaxisdata";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            $varnameX = "xData$val";
            $varnameY = "yData$val";
                $$varnameX[] = $row['xaxisdata'];
                $$varnameY[] = $row['yaxisdata'];
            }
        $myData->addPoints($varnameX,"XPID$val");
        $myData->addPoints($varnameY,"YPID$val");
        $myData->setSerieOnAxis("YPID$val",1);
        $myData->setScatterSerie("XPID$val","YPID$val",$i+1);
        $myData->setScatterSerieDescription($val,"Sample$val");
        }
```

Essentially i think my problem is in creating the variable names inside the WHILE loop (not sure correct way to generate increasing variable names), but I cant for the life of me figure out whats wrong. The $myData stuff is just for pChart, passing the arrays to the graphing script.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why are you suffixing the variable names to make them unique when they're arrays.... all you're doing is creating loads and loads of arrays that only contain a single entry

Comment: There will be lots of arrays. The SQL query pulls as many plots from the table as there are values in $pidresults.....i.e. the loop should be creating all the X and Y pairs where each one is an array anyway

Comment: Probably best to use an array of arrays then.

Comment: Does it matter that the arrays might all be different lengths when putting them all inside one multidimensional array though? Not all XY pairs will be the same length.

Comment: You check the docs carefully? http://wiki.pchart.net/doc.dataset.addpoints.html Pretty sure you can add the points at once. if you show us some how you want your chart to look like maybe it will be easier.

Comment: Won't matter to php that the arrays within an array are different lengths.

Answer (score 1):

You should use arrays.  You can then have the x's and y's as and array:

$x[0], $x[1], etc.

```
 for ($i=0; $i<=10; $i++)
  {
  $x[$i] = blah blah blah  //assigns the next incremental value of array $x
 }
```

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays.asp

Other ways to store these (two dimensional arrays for multiple series):

```
$x[$series][$i] //$x[0][0]  is the first x point in the first series
$y[$series][$i] //$y[0][0] is the first y point in the first series
```

For readability, you could also have $series be a string, eg 'series1' so

```
$x['series1'][0];
```

Comment: Hi ssaltman, so I would essentially be creating arrays inside arrays?

Comment: I dont even think you need arrays inside arrays. YOu could use a two dimensional array. I'll expand my answer so the code looks nice.

Answer (score 0):

I would be tempted to do it like this, assuming that masterID is an integer:-

```
$pidresults = $_SESSION['pidresults'];

// select plottable data from sampleSlave table

$sql = "SELECT masterID, xaxisdata, yaxisdata
        FROM sampleSlave 
        WHERE masterID IN =  ".implode(',', $pidresults)."
        AND xaxisdata >= 1 
        ORDER BY FIELD (masterID, ".implode(',', $pidresults)."), xaxisdata";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());

$varnameX = array();
$varnameY = array();

$prevMasterID = 0;
$i = 1;

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{
    if ($prevMasterID != $row['masterID'])
    {
        if ($prevMasterID != 0)
        {
            $myData->addPoints($varnameX,"XPID$prevMasterID");
            $myData->addPoints($varnameY,"YPID$prevMasterID");
            $myData->setSerieOnAxis("YPID$prevMasterID",1);
            $myData->setScatterSerie("XPID$prevMasterID","YPID$prevMasterID",$i++);
            $myData->setScatterSerieDescription($prevMasterID,"Sample$prevMasterID");
            $varnameX = array();
            $varnameY = array();
        }
        $prevMasterID = $row['masterID'];
    }
    $varnameX[] = $row['xaxisdata'];
    $varnameY[] = $row['yaxisdata'];
}
if ($prevMasterID != 0)
{
    $myData->addPoints($varnameX,"XPID$prevMasterID");
    $myData->addPoints($varnameY,"YPID$prevMasterID");
    $myData->setSerieOnAxis("YPID$prevMasterID",1);
    $myData->setScatterSerie("XPID$prevMasterID","YPID$prevMasterID",$i+1);
    $myData->setScatterSerieDescription($prevMasterID,"Sample$prevMasterID");
    $varnameX = array();
    $varnameY = array();
}
```

Note, no experience of pchart so that bitis pretty much copied from you

Comment: Thanks Kickstart. I had a go with that but no luck. I'm wondering if its more to do with the limitations of pChart. I'm going to re-read the docs and have a play over the weekend.

Comment: Afraid I have not use pchart at all. Possible that the parameters need to be passed in a different way but would need to do some digging to figure it out.